# Android - modificar un textview desde asynctask (doInBackground)

Tags: android, asynctask

Buenas:
Estoy haciendo un cliente de chat en Android que se conecta a un servidor local en java, y tengo ya todo prácticamente terminado.

Lo único que me falta es que los mensajes que recibe por la clase AsyncTask, que ejecuta un getinputstream del servidor, me lo escriba en el textview del mainactivity, pero al no tener acceso a la interfaz de usuario por estar en una clase secundaria no me deja, y no se como hacerlo.

Os copio por si os ayuda la parte del código que recibe los mensajes:

```
public void escribirMensaje(String m){
  tvChat.append(m + System.lineSeparator());
}
class RecibirMensajes extends AsyncTask {
  Socket socket;
  RecibirMensajes(Socket s){
      this.socket=s;
  }
  @Override
  protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
      // Obtiene el flujo de entrada del socket
      DataInputStream entradaDatos = null;
      String mensajeRecibido="";
      String mensajeAntiguo=mensajeRecibido;
      try {
          entradaDatos = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          System.out.println("Error al crear el stream de entrada: " + ex.getMessage());
      } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
          System.out.println("El socket no se creo correctamente. ");
      }

      // Bucle infinito que recibe mensajes del servidor
      boolean conectado = true;
      while (conectado) {
          try {
              mensajeRecibido = entradaDatos.readUTF();
              if(mensajeRecibido!=mensajeAntiguo){
                  escribirMensaje(mensajeRecibido);
                  mensajeAntiguo=mensajeRecibido;
              }
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              System.out.println("Error al leer del stream de entrada: " + ex.getMessage());
              conectado = false;
          } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
              System.out.println("El socket no se creo correctamente. " + ex.getMessage());
              conectado = false;
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
```

¡Espero que podáis ayudarme! Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: en doInBackground no puedes actualizar la UI busca por SOES como se usa el asyntask

Comment: disculpa, pero... que es SOES?

Comment: SOES: Stack Overflow ESpañol

Comment: De recomiendo que no hagas esta practica que es mala al usar una AsyncTask con while como haces descastes batería innecesaria al celular asi que mejor usas esta librería https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java hace lo que buscas en un tiempo real